# Titanium - Android 6 permissions

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, titanium-android

I'm having an error when I try to ask for permissions on Android 6.

My function is:

```
// check ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
var location2Permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
var hasLocation2Permission = Ti.Android.hasPermission(location2Permission);

if(!hasLocation2Permission){
    permissionsToRequest.push(location2Permission);
}

// request permission
Ti.Android.requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info("SUCCESS");
        callback();
    } else {
        Ti.API.info("ERROR: " + e.error);
    }
});
```

And the error is:

```
Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Android> has no method 'requestPermissions'
```

Whats happening? Because in Titanium Docs this function exists. I'm using Ti.SDK 5.1.2.GA

Comment: do you want to ask for location permission?

Comment: I think my problem is that in Ti.SDK 5.1.2.GA the function requestPermissions isn't implemented yet...

Comment: Yes you should Ti SDK 5.2.2 and up.

Comment: With Ti SDK 5.2.2 doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you checked the links provided in the answer, because its working for me.

Comment: Comes with Titanium SDK 5.4.0 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// The first argument is required on iOS and ignored on other platforms
var hasLocationPermissions = Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);
Ti.API.info('Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions', hasLocationPermissions);

if (hasLocationPermissions) {
    return alert('You already have permission.');
}

Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS, function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions', e);

    if (e.success) {

        // Instead, probably call the same method you call if hasLocationPermissions() is true
        alert('You granted permission.');

    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
        alert('You denied permission for now, forever or the dialog did not show at all because it you denied forever before.');

    } else {

        // We already check AUTHORIZATION_DENIED earlier so we can be sure it was denied now and not before
        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'You denied permission.',

            // We also end up here if the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is missing from tiapp.xml in which case e.error will say so
            message: e.error
        }).show();
    }
});
```

for more you can look in the [link](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js) and also in the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-requestLocationPermissions)